# Pattern search in Azure blob file names

Tags: c#, azure, search, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to search files that match my search pattern.

```
static void ListBlobsInFolder() {
            var account = <MyStorageAccount>
            var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var containerName = "importcontainer";
            var folderName = "subfolder";
            var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            var query = container.ListBlobs(prefix: folderName, useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.None);
            foreach(var item in query) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Uri.Segments.Last());
            }
        }
```

This gets me the list of files present in the subfolder.

Is there a way to return the files that only match a pattern. Example I want to retrieve file names that contains "abc" in it.

Is this possible in Azure ?

Comment: you can filter using a prefix but nothing more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to return the files that only match a pattern. Example
>   I want to retrieve file names that contains "abc" in it.

Unfortunately it is not possible. There's limited support for server-side searching in Azure Blob Storage. Only thing you can filter on is the blob prefix i.e. you can instruct Azure Storage service to only returns blobs names of which start with certain characters.

For your scenario, you will need to fetch the list of all blobs in a blob container and do the filtering on the client side.

Comment: *do the filtering on the client side.* -- That's exactly what I am trying to avoid. Anyway thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Has Microsoft has announced any plan to support more options for searching blobs? I mean, it's a simple string isn't it? When you can support `startsWith` then you gotta be able to support `contains` and `endsWith` too.

Comment: My guess is the internal structure of blob storage.  When you have millions of blobs in a container, doing a `contains` search requires iterating all of them.  Depending on a the internal structure of their storage, that could be intensive.  A `startsWith` lets you seek to a specific point in the storage hierarchy and iterate over a much small set of objects.  I can see the argument of "If you want 'contains', add it as metadata or an indexed tag.  Or use an external DB of some form, which points at the blobs".  Blobs, on the whole, are oriented around singular access.